# Excel coordinate(s) with c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want an Array(not a list converted to an Array), to assign only 1 coordinate something like "A4" should be accessed like `_excelCoordinate["A"][4]`, so I was thinking of a multidimensional array whith only one element(coordinate pair).

This is what I came up with:

```
private dynamic[,] _excelCoordinate;

_excelCoordinate = new[,] { { "" }, { 0 } };
```

But I get:

> No best type found for implicitly-typed array

And maybe no extra class, for that data structure.

How should it look the correct way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the type of the array you are creating (in this case `dynamic[,]`). The compiler cannot infer what the type of the array should be based on the elements (the string and the integer) provided in the array initializer.

```
_excelCoordinate  = new dynamic[,] { { "" }, { 0 } };
```